# using melpon/memoize in elixir mix task

Tags: elixir, memoization, elixir-mix

I am using [melpon/memoize](https://github.com/melpon/memoize) for cache in my phoenix aplication. It is working very well in runtime.

However, I have a few mix tasks in my application, which I execute sparingly.
Now these tasks eventually call a memoized function, for example:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.MyTask do
  use Mix.Task
  alias MemoizedModule
  require Logger;
  use Memoize

  def run(_) do
    MemoizedModule.get_value()
  end
end

defmodule MemoizedModule do
  use Memoize
  defmemo get_value() do
    1
  end
end
```

and it crashes with:

```
/opt/app # mix my_task
** (ArgumentError) errors were found at the given arguments:

  * 1st argument: no persistent term stored with this key

    :persistent_term.get(:memoize_cache_strategy)
    (memoize 1.4.0) lib/memoize/config.ex:29: Memoize.Config.cache_strategy/0
    (memoize 1.4.0) lib/memoize/cache.ex:11: Memoize.Cache.tab/1
    (memoize 1.4.0) lib/memoize/cache.ex:103: Memoize.Cache.do_get_or_run/3
    (mix 1.12.3) lib/mix/task.ex:394: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix 1.12.3) lib/mix/cli.ex:84: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir 1.12.3) lib/code.ex:1261: Code.require_file/2
```

If I try to execute the code inside IEx, it works as expected:

```
/opt/app # iex -S mix
Interactive Elixir (1.12.3) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Mix.Tasks.MyTask.run()
1
```

I know it has something to do with some initialization that is not done in mix tasks, but I can´t figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**We need to start applications explicitly in mix tasks.**

Codes are loaded, but applications are not started when running mix commands.

> Mix does not automatically start our application or any of its dependencies ...
> [Ref](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/intermediate/mix_tasks#loading-your-application-3)

So we need to start the it explicitly:

```
def run(_) do
  {:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:memoize)

  MemoizedModule.get_value()
end
```

You may need to change `:memoize` to `:my_otp_app` if you need other initialization tasks in the app.

**Why does it work inside `iex -S mix`?**

That's because `iex -S mix [run]` has started your application for you.